# HTML5 multi touch events from touch screen

Tags: hardware, multi-touch, touchscreen, html5

I have a Ubuntu machine with a 24" touchscreen and it is working fine. I can move the mouse, do gestures with several touch points and such so the hardware is working fine. Now I wonder if it is possible to make a browser interpret the events as touch and not as mousedown, mousedrag etc. HTML5 has really good support for touch and multiple touch and I would like to develop web applications for this setup. Does anyone have a clue on how to do this?

Comment: Interesting question. Chrome/Chromium seems lacking this on Linux [due to GTK](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=133735#c3). Firefox [says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Site_Compatibility_for_Firefox_18) "On Mac and Linux, touch events are not implemented yet."

Comment: Chromium running under Chromium OS with X but Aura instead of GTK has great multi-touch support. All the JS events are triggered exactly as they should.

Answer (score 1):

There is actually jQuery Mobile (http://jquerymobile.com/) a plugin for the jQuery JavaScript Framework, which offers touch events and gestures support for all devices.

Also check out http://www.jqmgallery.com/ to see some real life applications which are built with jQuery Mobile. ( in most cases you can spy on the source files for advanced real life examples)

Comment: The problem is not to build the webui, the code works perfectly on the exact same hardware but running Windows 7 + Chrome. The problem is that in Linux the touches are interpreted as mouseclicks in Chromium / Chrome and not as touchstart / touchend as it should.

Comment: doesn't jQuery Mobile circumvent the problem? if not, my best guess is, that the touchscreen is only recognized in fallback Mode as a generic Mouse and therefore no suitable driver is used. I found https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EloTouchScreen but is seems to be outdated. Try to search for your Touchscreen Vendor and "ubuntu driver" to find a working solution. Good Luck!