# Which browsers can properly handle non-mouse/keyboard input devices? (Eg touchscreens, graphics tablets, etc)

Tags: mouse, wacom, input-devices

[A W3C Recommendation (24 February 2015)](https://www.w3.org/TR/pointerevents/) defines events and related interfaces for handling *hardware agnostic pointer input from devices including a mouse, pen, touchscreen, etc*. Essentially letting web pages know when somebody is using something like a touchscreen, or a graphics tablet.

On Windows, [IE10+ has this ability](https://web.archive.org/web/20151207043341/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davrous/archive/2013/02/20/handling-touch-in-your-html5-apps-thanks-to-the-pointer-events-of-ie10-and-windows-8.aspx), but I haven't found any information about this on Linux environments. Do any browsers  in Ubuntu support this yet?

<sub>NOTE: There is a [Wacom plugin for their tablets](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Wacom_Tablet#Web_Browser_Plugin) but this *only* works with Wacom and is not standardized.</sub>

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/q/277546/47291

Answer (score 0):

[Can I use pointer events?](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer)

> Firefox support is disabled by default and only supports mouse input.
>   On Windows only, touch can be enabled with the
>   `layers.async-pan-zoom.enabled` and `dom.w3c_touch_events.enabled` flags

None of the other browsers seem to do so at the moment.